# what's the best algorithm to find a free connection in a pool?

Tags: algorithm, connection-pooling

I need to program an application that manages a pool of connection. I would like to know which algorithms should be studied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical Pool implementation would have a *free* bucket stack:

- when a connection is requested, pop it from the stack
- when a connection is given back to the pool, push it on the stack

This favors re-use of the last used connection, which is good for caching.

When giving a connection to the user, you'll use RAII so that it'll get back to the Pool automatically (and deterministically) when all references to it are dropped.

Now, it's up to you to decide how to handle the events:

- Request of a connection when there is none available (you can wait, build a new one, etc...)
- Get back a connection when there are already a lot of it in the stack (do we want to keep so many of them ?)

Those are implementation details of your pool and should be adapted depending on your requirements.

Comment: @ElTato: If this answers your question, you accept it as the correct answer (the tick to the left of the answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am still curious as to what kind of research have people done towards when and how many connections to provision/kill and if there exists some magic number for web APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is really no complicated algorithm necessary here. You just need two buckets, one for used connections and for free connections. At the beginning all connections are in the *free* bucket. If a connection is requested, you take one from the *free* bucket and put it in the *used* bucket. If it is no longer used, you put it back in the *free* bucket.